# What is the fundamental GUI library for Ubuntu starting with 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gui, ubuntu-touch, qt, qml

I have started exploring deeply into doing development for the Ubuntu phone.  In the past, and having used stock Ubuntu, I always found that GTK was the standard GUI library.  But now, with the phone development, I'm starting to see `QML` being the one that they encourage, and this uses QT.

So, which is the standard?  Has it changed?  How many of my applications are written in GTK and how many are actually in QT with good theme ?

Comment: I suggest you use whatever is recommended at http://developer.ubuntu.com for new development.

Comment: From that perspective, it would look like the tool of choice is "Quickly", and thus QML and Qt.  My strategy is probably QML with Haskell for when I need native code, and pure QML when I can do it all in Javascript.

Comment: My mistake... Quickly builds frameworks (quickly) for GTK applications.  QML is totally unrelated.  So my question really stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has taken me more than a year to find the answer to this, but Cannonical has finally made their position more clear.  They are migrating (generally) away from the GTK library and onto the QT library, and it is their intent for this to span from Ubuntu Touch to the desktop.

See [Why is Canonical choosing QT over GTK for Unity's next generation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281092/why-is-canonical-choosing-qt-over-gtk-for-unitys-next-generation) for the trail to a complete answer.